# Integrating Pyspark with Pycharm 2016

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pycharm, pyspark

I am new with Apache spark and am now trying to integrating it with the latest version of Pycharm IDE. I have seen several post on that, and so far I have come up to this.
Here is the configuration screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I have added both `SPARK_HOME` and `SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j.zip` here.

Then I have added the root path of `pyspark` and `py4j` in the project structure for getting the necessary modules for code completion.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Up to this, I could import the pyspark module in my IDE, but I have a problem when I run this basic program:

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewProject/Hello world.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewProject/Hello world.py", line 4, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
  File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 112, in __init__
  File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 245, in _ensure_initialized
  File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 79, in launch_gateway
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have shown the file path properly here which is actually `C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/README.md`
Is it a configuration  error, or is there anything wrong with this code?

I am using Python 3.5

Comment: Does this problem still exist in the most recent versions of this software? If yes, should the question be edited?

Comment: wrote an article on it recently https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707